# Using bindings with NSTableView/NSDictionaryController/Shared User Defaults

Tags: macos, nstableview, cocoa-bindings

I have a small dictionary in my Defaults.plist that I'd like to display in my preferences pane. So I...

1. added a NSTableView with two columns to my prefs screen
2. added an NSDictionaryController to the scene
3. bound the dict controller to Shared User Defaults Controller and set the Key Path to the dictionary ("Variables")
4. bound the table columns to arrangedObjects->key and ->value

I did NOT bind anything to the table itself, only the columns. At this point if I run the app:

[image]

Interesting point: the number of lines is correct, there are four entries in the dictionary, and if I add or remove any, the display changes to the same value again. So the table is getting *something* from the DictController at least.

I've tried to bind to various bits of the UI - not the column itself but the objects inside it, etc. I also tried binding at the table level, but I'm not sure what key path I would use in that case. In any event, everything I try either makes it crash on running, stops Xcode from compiling the storyboard, or causes the entire computer to die with "out of application memory".

I've looked at Apple's docs, which lack even a single complete example that I can find, as well as some 3rd party pages on the topic, but everything suggests this should [just work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933493/simple-nstableview-bindings-example). Any ideas?

Comment: Is the tableview view based or cell based?

Comment: Cell based, and it's not the same table as we discussed before.

Comment: A view based tableview displays "Table View Cell", a cell based tableview doesn't. It looks like your tableview is view based.

Comment: Right you are, and changing it fixed it. For future reference though, when I am using a view based table, how do I bind to that?

Comment: Don't bind the columns. Bind the content of the tableview to `arrangedObjects` and bind the textfields in the columns to `Table Cell View` with key path `objectValue.key`. [Populating a Table View Using Cocoa Bindings](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/PopulatingViewTablesWithBindings/PopulatingView-TablesWithBindings.html)

Comment: Any luck yet? Have you any hints to spare for people such as I, with similar need?

Comment: @MottiShneor - Willeke's answer above fixed it.